# cast to array of integer invalid syntax

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT string_to_array(code, '.')::int[] FROM "accounts" ORDER BY code ASC, "name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

in my localhost, with `postgresql 10.10` the query works well, but when I try the query on my development server with `postgresql 9.5.11` it throwing errors `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

what could be wrong?

EDIT:
the following query

```
SELECT string_to_array(code, '.') FROM "accounts" ORDER BY code ASC, "name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

give the same result in both version, as follow:

```
string_to_array
{1,0,0,0,0,0}
{1,1,0,0,0,0}
{1,1,1,0,0,0}
{1,1,1,1,0,0}
{1,1,1,2,0,0}
{1,1,2,0,0,0}
{1,1,2,1,0,0}
{1,1,2,10,0,0}
{1,1,2,11,0,0}
{1,1,2,12,0,0}
```

Comment: It seems that your `code`value contains an empty part, maybe `123..456`. So, the cast cannot work because the middle part is no valid integer value. Do you know the relevant value? I am wondering that this work in version 10 (at the fiddle it does not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=681081e7130d23f01422880c344812e0)

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question and I don't see any empty part in it.

Comment: Is '{1,0,0,0,0,0}' the string to be converted or already the array? If it is the original value: Your sting does not contain a `.`, so a splitting is not possible. If it is already the array: This works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=420c69784b1e4fe1e81b3530d42412d0 Can you try to reproduce your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: nevermind. when I double check using `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE char_length(code)<11` there are about 30 rows returned. I think that's the issue coming from.